# Social login with Cognito on React Native and React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I have a problem that I using Amplify for social login on web application, now I have to add social login function for mobile application. But I find that redirect url for mobile is myapp:// in order to use deeplink. How can I use redirect url on web as deepLink on mobile for action back to my mobile app after user sign-in with Google, Facebook?

Thanks in advance!